# GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin cannot be loaded in gensim models MemoryError

Tags: python, gensim

I have been trying to load GoogleNews Vector file to gensim models. The program never finished loading and I keep getting MemoryError. A few days ago, I didn't have that problem. I don't know why I get this problem all of a sudden.

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('../../data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)  

## Above is my simplified python file and how I load the model. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('../../data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)  
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 1549, in load_word2vec_format
    limit=limit, datatype=datatype)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 286, in _load_word2vec_format
    vocab_size, vector_size, datatype, unicode_errors, binary_chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 205, in _word2vec_read_binary
    result, counts, chunk, vocab_size, vector_size, datatype, unicode_errors)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 190, in _add_bytes_to_result
    _add_word_to_result(result, counts, word, vector, vocab_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 169, in _add_word_to_result
    result.vocab[word] = gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab(index=word_id, count=word_count)
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `MemoryError` because your system lacks enough RAM to finish the operation.

The `GoogleNews` vectors are over 3GB on disk, and require more RAM than that to load into the Python object heap. Even if you were doing nothing else on the same machine, it's doubtful you could do much with them on a system with 4GB of RAM - you'd need 8GB, or more, depending on what else is using memory on the machine, and in your Python process(es).

If the same step was succeeding a few days ago, it is certain that the system you were using then (even if the same system as now) had more free memory *at the time you attempted the load* then, compared to now.

Your options are:

- move to a system with more RAM (perhaps by upgrading the one yo are using)
- load a smaller set of vectors

The Gensim `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()` method takes an optional `limit` parameter which only reads exactly that many words from the front of the supplied file. As the `GoogleNews` model includes 3 million words, using something like `limit=500000` loads jut 1/6th of the words, and thus uses about 1/6th of the RAM.

That's still a ton of words! And, as such models typically list the most-frequently-used words first, a `limit=500000` only discards less-frequently-used words. Sometimes with natural-language-processing, discarding *more* of the rare words can even *improve* results on common tasks. (Rarer word senses-of-meaning can vary more, their vectors are often lower-quality as they've been trained on fewer examples, and yet altogether they are quite numerous overall – sometimes making their inclusion cost more in model size, and processing time, than any incremental meaning they deliver.)

Separately, and unlikely to be a major factor in your issue: it appears you're using a years-old version of Gensim. Generally, efficiency with regard to memory-usage and task-runtimes will improve with later versions. So no matter how you get around this particular `MemoryError`, you should generally prefer to use a current version of Gensim, such as 4.2.0 (as of this writing in June 2022).

Comment: I was running this program two weeks ago. It was fine. Could it be Gensim version on that server changed within that two weeks?

Comment: During load, there shouldn’t be much if any difference in memory used by different versions- so it’s more likely other things now consuming more memory. Is the server have other things running on it, & are other people changing its software & your Python environment’s libraries? (Can you run tools like `top` to monitor other processes on it?) How much RAM does the server have?

Comment: It seems to be working when I move the files and programs to different server with more memory available. I forgot the fact that the old server has growing data and it is about to be full. Thank you. We diagnosed two problems at once.